Keggscape Network is not showing nodes properly
I need to know how to fix this issue. No matter what pathway I use, the nodes are not displayed as shown on the keggscape website. Instead, they show up like this:

For reference, I used this pathway: https://www.genome.jp/pathway/hsa04152#

Please [edit] your question and highlight the specific issue. Is it that the node names aren't within the node boxes? Or is it something else?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

please refer to the link to see how the network is supposed to be like for the best understanding of the issue thank you

We are aware of the issue and are working on it. For some reason, the Keggscape styles are not getting applied but it is now fixed.  Please install the latest version.

Can you kindly described the versions where the bug was discovered and the version where it was fixed? The reason is that each post exists long after posting as a reference to others
